# Visual Studio 2010 says it built DLL but didn't

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll

I'm attempting to build both a .DLL and a .lib for the latest SQLite3 release. I created a new project in Visual Studio 2010, chose Visual C++ / Win 32 / Win 32 Project, and chose the DLL option. (Although it has ".NET Framework 4" as a pop-up menu selected. Is this an issue? I don't want to require the .NET framework.)

When I build the project, it seems to work:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SQLite3, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  shell.c
1>  sqlite3.c
1>  Generating code
1>  Finished generating code
1>  SQLite3.vcxproj -> c:\users\jensenv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\SQLite3\Release\SQLite3.dll
```

But there is no SQLite3.dll in that directory. There are a lot of log files, plus shell.obj, sqlite3.obj, SQLite3.og, and vc100.pdb. Why does it say it created a .dll when there is none there?

And is there anything I need to do to get it to create a matching .lib (exports symbols) too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are looking in:

> c:\users\jensenv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\SQLite3\Release

And not in:

> c:\users\jensenv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\SQLite3\SQLite3\Release

The first one contains final DLLs/EXEs, while the second one contains intermediate files like .obj files.